# Function to call Highcharts with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts, lazy-loading

Fixed the initial issue of the code failing to run.  Can't seem to pinpoint the location or segment throwing the errors at the bottom of this post.

A user may click a link and an ajax call is initiated.  The ajax call embeds the following source in the head of the page if it does not exist, then it calls the dothis function.  The issue is popping up when the call is made to getlegislators(uid);

```
$('#votescode').ready(function() {    

                 function dothis(){

    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
                            return {
                                radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.2, r: 0.7
                                                },
                                stops: [
                                    [0, color],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]
                                ]
                            };
                        });
                $('#container').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: null,
                            plotShadow: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                size: 200,
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: '#000000',
                                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        credits:{enabled:false},
                        exporting:{enabled:false},
                        colors:['#ADD46D','#F1744F','#b9e376','#f2a48d'],
                        series: [{
                            type: 'pie',
                            name: 'Browser share',
                            data: [
                                ['Supports You',   1.0],
                                ['Opposes You',       1.0],
                                ['Absent on Supporting',    0.0],
                                ['Absent on Opposing',    0.0]
                            ]
                        }]
                    });
                 }
                 dothis();

    });
```

Here's a copy of ajax.js which is initiated upon the user clicking:

```
    function getXMLHttp()
    {
      var xmlHttp

      try
      {
        //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        //Internet Explorer
        try
        {
          xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          try
          {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch(e)
          {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return xmlHttp;
    }
    function getcmtename(chamb){
          var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?chamb="+chamb+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function MakeRequest(iorf)
    {
      var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?req="+iorf+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function getsch(iorf)
    {
      var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse5(xmlHttp2.responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?p=comm&chamb="+iorf+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp2.send(null);
    }
    function getfloorvotes(rcnum,type,syr,sind,chamb){

    if(document.getElementById("votescode")){


        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse2(xmlHttp.responseText);
          //BELOW GENERATES CHART CODE
              var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
            xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
            {
              HandleResponse4(xmlHttp2.responseText);
              dothis();
                }
            }
            xmlHttp2.open("GET", "billajax.php?&p=vc&chamb="+chamb+"&type="+type+"&syr="+syr+"&sid="+sind+"&rcnum="+rcnum+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
            xmlHttp2.send(null);

        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "billajax.php?&p=bvotes&chamb="+chamb+"&type="+type+"&syr="+syr+"&sid="+sind+"&rcnum="+rcnum+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);


    }else{

        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse2(xmlHttp.responseText);

          //BELOW GENERATES CHART CODE
      var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
        xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse3(xmlHttp2.responseText);
          dothis();
        }
      }
      xmlHttp2.open("GET", "billajax.php?&p=vc&chamb="+chamb+"&type="+type+"&syr="+syr+"&sid="+sind+"&rcnum="+rcnum+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp2.send(null);


        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "billajax.php?&p=bvotes&chamb="+chamb+"&type="+type+"&syr="+syr+"&sid="+sind+"&rcnum="+rcnum+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);



    }

    }
    function getlegislators(uid){

    if(document.getElementById("votescode")){
         var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse10(xmlHttp.responseText);
          var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
            xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
            {
              HandleResponse11(xmlHttp2.responseText);
              dothis();
              dothis2();
                }
            }
            xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=glv&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
            xmlHttp2.send(null);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?p=gl&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
         var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse10(xmlHttp.responseText);
          var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
            xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
            {
              HandleResponse12(xmlHttp2.responseText);
              dothis();
              dothis2();
                }
            }
            xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=glv&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
            xmlHttp2.send(null);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?p=gl&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    }

    function gettracks(uid){
         var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse10(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?p=gt&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function getMembers(iorf)
    {
      var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?p=l&req="+iorf+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function HandleResponse(response)
    {
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      document.getElementById('selissues').innerHTML = response;
      var shn = $('.shtn').ThreeDots();
      shn.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:1});
    }
    function HandleResponse10(response)
    {
      var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      document.getElementById('initiative').innerHTML = response;
      //var shn = $('.shtn').ThreeDots();
      //shn.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:1});
    }
    function HandleResponse5(response2)
    {
      var idid = 'waiting';
      toggle_visibility(idid);
      document.getElementById('org_activity').innerHTML = response2;
      var shn = $('.shtn').ThreeDots();
      shn.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:1});
    }
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    function HandleResponse2(response)
    {
      //var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      document.getElementById('billinfor').innerHTML = response;
      //var shn = $('.shtn').ThreeDots();
      //shn.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:1});
      var bsy = $('.billsy').ThreeDots();
      bsy.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:3});
    }
    function HandleResponse3(response)
    {
      //var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
    script.innerHTML = response;
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    }
    function HandleResponse4(response)
    {
      //var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      var el = document.getElementById( 'votescode' );
    el.parentNode.removeChild( el );

       var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
    script.innerHTML = response;
    document.head.appendChild(script);


    }
    function HandleResponse11(response)
    {
      //var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      var el = document.getElementById( 'votescode' );
    el.parentNode.removeChild( el );

       var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
    script.innerHTML = response;
    document.head.appendChild(script);


    }
    function HandleResponse12(response)
    {
      //var idid = 'waiting';
      //toggle_visibility(idid);
      var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
    script.innerHTML = response;
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    }
```

Here's an excerpt of the error from the console of the browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ThreeDots' index.php:129
makesmalll index.php:129
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433
completed

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
dothis
(anonymous function)
o jquery.min.js:2
p.add jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.ready jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)
HandleResponse12 ajax.js:317
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange ajax.js:184
Uncaught ReferenceError: dothis is not defined ajax.js:185
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: have you given reference of highchart js?

Comment: You need to call this after everything has finished loading, i.e. use jQuery's `ready` method. On jsfiddle, select "onDomready" from the dropbox to the left and it will work, that's the equivalent.

Comment: Of course, the jsfiddle won't run, and I have a similar setup on other pages that works fine.

Comment: So all works properly  ?

Comment: How it is related with highcharts, if you have errors in ajax.js / jquery files ?

Comment: Initially I thought the issue was related to highcharts, IngoBurk resolved that issue which lead me to look at the remainder of the code.  I removed the tag accordingly.  

Still can't seem to make sense of the error, I'm doing the same thing on another page without any errors and it works fine.  I duplicated an existing function that works properly.

Comment: The javascript is generated and inserted into the document's head properly.  It will not execute the code with dothis(); or dothis2();,  functions that are injected into the document's head.  Error is simply Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts';

Answer (score 0):

Use the `src` attribute instead of AJAX to lazy load `HighCharts`, alias it to `jQuery` as a property, then call the dependent code:

```
var jqScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var hcScript = document.createElement('script');
hcScript.src = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";

document.documentElement.insertBefore(hcScript, jqScript);

hcScript.onload = function () {
  $.highcharts = HighCharts;
  dothis();
};
```